# create a list of dates without importing data in R

Tags: r, date

Does R have a package where I can create a set of dates from two periods without importing data?

Example:

to create a list from "1/13/2014" to 1/13/15" for each day how can I do this?

EDIT: This is NOT a duplicate. Seq() package shows no example for dates in this format: "mm/dd/yy". Seq() package only has "1994-01-01" format. Please help here.

Comment: Still a duplicate as far as I'm concerned. The answer to the other question even shows how to tackle a specific formatting of the date series output. It would be a tiny adaptation to fit the exact needs of your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is done with `seq`

```
seq(as.Date("2014-01-13"), as.Date("2015-01-13"), by="days")
```

you can wrap it in `format` to change the month, day, year order:

```
format(seq(as.Date("2014-01-13"), as.Date("2015-01-13"), by="days"), format="%m-%d-%Y")
```

Comment: how can we get to an output that has mm/dd/yy format?

Comment: @TyrionLannister See the first _Example_ in `?format.Date`

Comment: Thanks jalapic. This does it, but I used format(seq(as.Date("2014-01-13"), as.Date("2015-01-13"), by="days"), format="%m/%d/%Y") to get there.